# How do I rename my hamster?

Tags: professor-layton-diabolical-box

While on the train I got a hamster for an exercise minigame. I initially named it Hammy, but I'd like to change it. Is there a way to rename the hamster?

[image: Hamster minigame]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having beaten the game, there seems to be no way to rename your hamster after you've gotten them.